# Can't override Angular Material Colors with theme scss file

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material, angular-material-6

Following the instructions [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming), I created a theme.scss file for my Angular 7 project.

I added it to my angular.json file, and testing it with some simple non-material rules it's being imported and compiled fine.

```
"styles": ["node_modules/pb-design-system/dist/css/designsystem.css", "src/theme.scss", "src/styles.scss"],
```

However, no matter what I do, my primary button is still using Indigo.

To test it, I'm trying cyan:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();


$pbds-primary: mat-palette($mat-cyan);
$pbds-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

$pbds-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$pbds-theme: mat-light-theme($pbds-primary, $pbds-accent, $pbds-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($pbds-theme);
```

When I inspect the button in dev tools, I see

```
.mat-flat-button.mat-primary, .mat-raised-button.mat-primary, .mat-fab.mat-primary, .mat-mini-fab.mat-primary {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
}
```

for the html:

```
<button color="primary" mat-flat-button>OK</button>
```

Shouldn't the button now be Cyan 500? I am confused.

I also see no reference to `theme.scss` affecting the button in the styles inspector in dev tools.

Comment: Did you removed import of the pre-set theme, you have been using until now (in the `styles.scss` propably).

Comment: deleting my answer as the answer  does not talk of creating themes.

Comment: @romanSG I did not notice that when I installed Angular Material it in fact modified my styles.scss.  That explains it.

Comment: So now its working like it should ? :)

Comment: @romanSG It seems to be. Thanks.